# How to remove linux external kernel module which is installed with "make modules_install" command?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I found that, I can install an externel linux kernel module with "make modules && make modules_install" command, which will copy the *.ko file (such as test.ko) into /lib/modules/ directory.

But when I try to uninstall (not unload) the kernel module, I found that there is no command like "make modules_uninstall" to do that.
I tried to remote the .ko file in /lib/modules/ directory, but the module's information still can be found with "modinfo test" command. So, the module's infomation is still remain in the system.

Is there a way to totally uninstall the external kernel module from the system?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After you removed the .ko file(s), you also need to run `/sbin/depmod -a` to update the information about available modules.

Comment: `modules_install` installs the .ko in different folers, sometimes `extra` sometimes `updates` depending on RHEL or Fedora.